# How to switch between keyboard layouts in Xubuntu without it changing itself back

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout, xfce

I have installed Xubuntu 20.04 on a machine.

Under "Keyboard" settings I have unchecked "use system defaults" and added an extra keyboard layout.

I want to be able to switch between the 2 layouts easily using an applet on the panel, so I have added the "Keyboard layouts" applet.

When I click this, it changes the keyboard layout. However it doesn't stick - as soon as I move to another window, it changes back. If I open a terminal, I have to change it every single time.

I would just like the layout to stick to what I set it to, until I change it back myself by clicking on the applet again.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you have to set keyboard shortcut in **Change layout option** to stick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting you need is in the **Keyboard layouts** applet properties.

Right-click on the language flag and click on **Properties**. Change the **Manage layout** option to **Globally**.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed! I had not thought to check the properties of the applet itself.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu (with GNOME) there is an option "Use different input sources for each window". It defaults to "false".

I suppose there is an equivalent setting in Xubuntu, and that you accidentally have set it to "true". So try to find that setting, and disable it.